# What is the logic behind this nvidia 's arctan2?

Tags: c, nvidia, numerical-methods, polynomial-math, atan2

Nvidia has some functions in Cg 3.1 Toolkit Documentation

arctan2 is [implemented](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/cg/atan2.html) as follows

```c
float2 atan2(float2 y, float2 x)
{
  float2 t0, t1, t2, t3, t4;

  t3 = abs(x);
  t1 = abs(y);
  t0 = max(t3, t1);
  t1 = min(t3, t1);
  t3 = float(1) / t0;
  t3 = t1 * t3;

  t4 = t3 * t3;
  t0 =         - float(0.013480470);
  t0 = t0 * t4 + float(0.057477314);
  t0 = t0 * t4 - float(0.121239071);
  t0 = t0 * t4 + float(0.195635925);
  t0 = t0 * t4 - float(0.332994597);
  t0 = t0 * t4 + float(0.999995630);
  t3 = t0 * t3;

  t3 = (abs(y) > abs(x)) ? float(1.570796327) - t3 : t3;
  t3 = (x < 0) ?  float(3.141592654) - t3 : t3;
  t3 = (y < 0) ? -t3 : t3;

  return t3;
}
```

What is the formula or logic behind this ? I couldn't find any references in their libraries.

Comment: It looks like it is using a polynomial to approximate the function, and is using Horner's method to evaluate the polynomial.

Comment: @IanAbbott which polynomial equation ?

Comment: It looks to be a polynomial of the form y = x + a*x^3 + b*x^5 + c*x^7....... The coefficients a, b... are chosen in such a way that the maximum error will be minimized.

Comment: @Elec1 The coefficients are in Horner's scheme, not standard form.

Comment: @Ian Abbot I know. But that's only a difference in the representation. Both styles are equivalent. It is clear that the coefficients in both forms are not equal. But they can be easily transformed from one form into the other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code has 3 parts.

First the input, which can be interpreted as a point (x,y), gets mapped to the sector below the diagonal in the first quadrant. The absolute values and max/min operations effectively act as reflections (or identity) first on the coordinate axes and then on the diagonal.

In the middle then an arcus or inverse tangent approximation for `r=y/x` is computed. Note that the Taylor series is `a = 1*r-1/3*r^3+1/5*r^5-1/7*r^7+...` However, the Taylor series is overly correct at the origin and rapidly loses accuracy away from it. Using some fitting procedure, a polynomial that is equally good/bad on the whole interval was determined. Its coefficients are close to the Taylor coefficients, especially in the lower degrees. The polynomial evaluation is most efficiently done via the Horner scheme, where the coefficients are used starting from the highest degree.

And finally, the signs and magnitudes of the input are used to undo the original reflections in reverse order, only that now the angle `a` gets transformed. So if there was a reflection on the diagonal, `a` gets mapped to `pi/2-a`. If there was a reflection on the `y` axis, `a` gets mapped to `pi-a`. And finally in case of a reflection on the `x` axis, `a` gets changed to `-a`.

---

With some recursive function calls, the procedure in question could also be compactly formulated as (here in Python)

```python
def atan2(y,x):
    if y<0: return -atan2(-y,x)
    if x<0: return pi-atan2(y,-x)
    if x<y: return 0.5*pi-atan2(x,y)
    return p(y/x)
```

where the polynomial is evaluated as

```python
def p(r):
    r2 = r*r
    res =        - 0.013480470  # *r^11
    res = res*r2 + 0.057477314  # *r^9
    res = res*r2 - 0.121239071  # *r^7 
    res = res*r2 + 0.195635925  # *r^5 
    res = res*r2 - 0.332994597  # *r^3 
    res = res*r2 + 0.999995630  # *r^1 
    return r*res
```

---

For comparison the Taylor series can be implemented as

```python
def a11(r):
    r2 = r*r
    res = 0
    for k in range(11,0,-2):
        res = 1/k-r2*res
    return r*res
```

To compare the errors of both approximations in one plot, use a logarithmic vertical axis, the Taylor error grows too fast.

```python
r = np.linspace(0,1,500)
plt.semilogy(r,abs(p(r)-np.arctan(r)), r, abs(a11(r)-np.arctan(r)))
plt.legend(["residual of p", "residual of Taylor"])
plt.grid(); plt.show()
```

This gives the error plot

[image: error plot]

which shows the described error behavior of the minimaxed polynomial and the Taylor polynomial of equal degree.

Comment: >> The polynomial evaluation 

what is the polynomial that is used and the rationale behind it ?

Comment: The polynomial is, slightly shortened, `r*(+0.9999+r^2*(-0.3329+r^2*(+0.1956+r^2*(-0.1212+r^2...))))` `= 0.9999*r - 0.3329*^3 + 0.1956*r^5 - 0.1212*r^7 + ...`

Comment: @njuffa it worked for y/x  > 1 too

Comment: Thanks a lot Lutz for the detailed analysis.